# Python print csv column value before output of each result without repeating

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a Python script that imports a list of url's from a CSV named list.csv, scrapes them and outputs any anchor text and href links found on each url from the csv:

(For reference the list of urls in the csv are all in column A)

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas
import csv

contents = []
with open('list.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents
    

for url in contents: 
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if len(link.text)>0:
            print(url, link.text, '-', link.get('href'))
```

The output results look something like this where https://www.example.com/csv-url-one/ and https://www.example.com/csv-url-two/ are the url's in column A in the csv:

```
['https://www.example.com/csv-url-one/'] Creative - https://www.example.com/creative/
['https://www.example.com/csv-url-one/'] Web Design - https://www.example.com/web-design/
['https://www.example.com/csv-url-two/'] PPC - https://www.example.com/ppc/
['https://www.example.com/csv-url-two/'] SEO - https://www.example.com/seo/
```

The issue is i want the output results to look more like this i.e not repeatedly print the url in the CSV before each result AND have a break after each line from the CSV:

```
['https://www.example.com/csv-url-one/'] 
Creative - https://www.example.com/creative/
Web Design - https://www.example.com/web-design/

['https://www.example.com/csv-url-two/'] 
PPC - https://www.example.com/ppc/
SEO - https://www.example.com/seo/
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: can't this be fixed by adding `print(url)` before 
    `for link in soup.find_all('a'):`

Comment: Oh yes it does. Thanks. Sorry im new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following solve your problem?

```py
for url in contents: 
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    print('\n','********',', '.join(url),'********','\n')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if len(link.text)>0:
            print(link.text, '-', link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Simply add `\n` at the end of `print`.
`\n` is a break line special character.

```py
for url in contents: 
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if len(link.text)>0:
            print(url, ('\n'), link.text, '-', link.get('href'), ('\n'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a separation between urls add a `\n` before printing each url.

If you want to print the urls only if it has valid links ie`if len(link.text)>0:`, use the for loop to save valid links to a list, and only print url and links if this list is not empty.

try this:

```py
for url in contents: 
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    
    valid_links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if len(link.text)>0:
            valid_links .append(link.text)

    if len (valid_links ):
        print('\n', url)
        for item in valid_links :
            print(item.text, '-', item.get('href')))
```